# Very simple, terse and easy GUI programming “frameworks”

Tags: user-interface, scripting, open-source, declarative

Please list GUI programming libraries, toolkits, frameworks which allow to write GUI apps *quickly*. I mean in such a way, that

- GUI is described entirely in a human-readable (and human-writable) plain text file (code)
- code is terse (1 or 2 lines of code per widget/event pair), suitable for scripting
- structure and operation of the GUI is evident from the code (nesting of widgets and flow of events)
- details about *how* to build the GUI are hidden (things like mainloop, attaching event listeners, etc.)
- auto-layouts are supported (vboxes, hboxes, etc.)

As answers suggest, this may be defined as *declarative* GUI programming, but it is not necessarily such. Any approach is OK if it works, is easy to use and terse.

There are some GUI libraries/toolkits like this. They are listed below. Please extend the list if you see a qualifying toolkit missing. Indicate if the project is crossplatform, mature, active, and give an example if possible.

Please use this wiki to discuss *only Open Source* projects.

This is the list so far (in alphabetical order):

#### Fudgets

[Fudgets](http://www.md.chalmers.se/Cs/Research/Functional/Fudgets/Intro/ex2.html) is a Haskell library. Platform: Unix. Status: Experimental, but still maintained. An example:

```
  import Fudgets
  main = fudlogue (shellF "Hello" (labelF "Hello, world!" >+< quitButtonF))
```

[image: Fudgets example screenshot]
<sub>(source: [picamatic.com](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/01/28/02/40/1883597_93x80.gif))</sub>

#### GNUstep Renaissance

[Renaissance](http://www.gnustep.it/Renaissance/Screenshots.html) allows to describe GUI in simple XML. Platforms: OSX/GNUstep. Status: part of GNUstep. An example below:

```
<window title="Example">
  <vbox>
    <label font="big">
      Click the button below to quit the application
    </label>
    <button title="Quit" action="terminate:"/>
  </vbox>
</window>
```

[image: Renaissance example screenshot]
<sub>(source: [picamatic.com](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/01/28/03/19/1884098_289x80.png))</sub>

#### HTML

HTML-based GUI (HTML + JS). Crossplatform, mature. Can be used entirely on the client side.

Looking for a nice “helloworld” example.

[image: HTML GUI example]
<sub>(source: [picamatic.com](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/01/28/02/44/1883635_264x60.png))</sub>

#### JavaFX

[JavaFX](http://hackety.org/2007/05/09/soGooeyCanYouSeeTheButton.html) is usable for standalone (desktop) apps as well as for web applications. Not completely crossplatform, not yet completely open source. Status: 1.0 release. An example:

```
  Frame {
    content: Button {
      text: "Press Me"
      action: operation() {
         System.out.println("You pressed me");
      }
    }
    visible: true
  }
```

*Screenshot is needed.*

#### Phooey

[Phooey](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phooey#One_example.2C_two_interfaces) is another Haskell library. Crossplatform (wxWidgets), HTML+JS backend planned. Mature and active. An example (a little more than a helloworld):

```
  ui1 :: UI ()
  ui1 = title "Shopping List" $
        do a <- title "apples"  $ islider (0,10) 3
           b <- title "bananas" $ islider (0,10) 7
           title "total" $ showDisplay (liftA2 (+) a b)
```

[image: Phooey example screenshot]
<sub>(source: [picamatic.com](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/01/28/02/33/1883543_236x187.png))</sub>

#### PythonCard

[PythonCard](http://pythoncard.sourceforge.net/index.html) describes GUI in a Python dictionary. Crossplatform (wxWidgets). Some apps use it, but the project seems stalled. There is an active fork.

*I skip [PythonCard example](http://www.halfcooked.com/presentations/osdc/pythoncard.html) because it is too verbose for the contest.*

[image: PythonCard example screenshot]
<sub>(source: [picamatic.com](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/01/28/02/46/1883646_199x99.gif))</sub>

#### Shoes

[Shoes](http://shoooes.net/tutorial/) for Ruby. Platforms: Win/OSX/GTK+. Status: Young but active. A minimal app looks like this:

```
  Shoes.app {
     @push = button "Push me"
     @note = para "Nothing pushed so far"
     @push.click {
        @note.replace "Aha! Click!"
     }
  }
```

[image: Shoes example screenshot]
<sub>(source: [picamatic.com](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/01/28/03/14/1884011_227x71.png))</sub>

#### Tcl/Tk

[Tcl/Tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/488). Crossplatform (its own widget set). Mature (probably even dated) and active. An example:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env wish
  button .hello -text "Hello, World!" -command { exit }
  pack .hello
  tkwait window .
```

[image: Tcl/Tk example screenshot]
<sub>(source: [picamatic.com](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/01/28/02/51/1883672_111x58.png))</sub>

#### tekUI

[tekUI](http://tekui.neoscientists.org/) for Lua (and C). Platforms: X11, DirectFB. Status: Alpha (usable, but API still evolves). An example:

```
  #/usr/bin/env lua
  ui = require "tek.ui"
  ui.Application:new {
    Children = {
      ui.Window:new  {
        Title = "Hello",
        Children = {
          ui.Text:new {
            Text = "_Hello, World!", Style = "button", Mode = "button",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }:run()
```

[image: tekUI helloworld screenshot]
<sub>(source: [picamatic.com](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/01/28/03/01/1883821_290x55.png))</sub>

#### Treethon

[Treethon](http://code.google.com/p/treethon/) for Python. It describes GUI in a YAML file (*Python in a YAML tree*). Platform: GTK+. Status: work in proress. A simple app looks like this:

```
  _import: gtk
  view: gtk.Window()
  add:
      - view: gtk.Button('Hello World')
        on clicked: print view.get_label()
```

[Treethon helloworld screenshot http://treethon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/treethon_gtk_tutorial/base.png](http://treethon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/treethon_gtk_tutorial/base.png)

#### Yet unnamed Python library by Richard Jones:

This one is not released yet. The idea is to use Python context managers (`with` keyword) to structure GUI code. See [Richard Jones' blog](http://www.mechanicalcat.net/richard/log/Python/Something_I_m_working_on.3) for details.

```
with gui.vertical:
    text = gui.label('hello!')
    items = gui.selection(['one', 'two', 'three'])
    with gui.button('click me!'):
        def on_click():
            text.value = items.value
            text.foreground = red
```

#### XUL

[XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner) + Javascript may be used to create stand-alone desktop apps with XULRunner as well as Mozilla extensions. Mature, open source, crossplatform.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
  <window id="main" title="My App" width="300" height="300"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <caption label="Hello World"/>
  </window>
```

[image: XUL helloworld example]
<sub>(source: [picamatic.com](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/01/28/03/27/1884209_228x108.png))</sub>

---

Thank your for contributions!

Comment: Might make a good Community Wiki.

Comment: Ok, I republished it as Community Wiki. But I hope it will not mention non-Open Source tools.

Comment: Could you add screenshots of the result.

Comment: Some of the links have screenshots already. However, most of these libs use cross-platform (or directly native) low-level toolkits. So they have more or less native look anywhere. Tk, Fudgets and JavaFX are different.

Comment: OK, I added screenshots. Also rewrote the question as a wiki page.

Answer (score 16):

Not to kid, but HTML.

It's cross-platform, and sums up the gui-layout in a simple textfile.  It's definitely mature, as well as well-understood and well documented.

There's a bunch of ways to template HTML files for dynamic content, and other ways to convert custom syntaxes to HTML if you dislike angle-brackets.

Client-side scripting w/ Javascript, server-side scripting with PHP/Ruby/Python/Perl.

It's not well suited for all purposes, but for many, it's good enough.  There's no reason that it has to be served either - you can distribute a HTML file to your clients if you want - see [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) for a good example of where that can go.

Comment: Web-based apps are OK, but the overall complexity of the thing is higher, due to unavoidable client-server interaction. Also, the # of lines of code per “event” is higher even with the latest web and js frameworks. And if an application is not entirely user-request driven, things become more tricky.

Comment: I think that HTML is an excellent way to make a GUI. You can make it simple, or fairly complex.  I have considered doing this myself for a file dialog, and probably will soon.

Comment: Your example with TiddlyWiki convinced me that it is suitable for purely client-side GUIs.

Comment: I've added a link to http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

Comment: HTML... Not enough for heavy CAD-like tools which handle data structures of sizes in range of GBs. Thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

What you're describing is, with the exception of shoes, the new-fangled notion of declarative programming. I'd describe shoes more as a GUI [Domain-Specifc Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). Well, I say new-fangled: Visual Basic forms, if you looked behind the IDE designer, were declarative. So, going further back still, were Oracle's SQL*Forms, although assembling them with a text editor was a process only to be be undertaken by the very bravest.

To add another to the list, Microsoft have [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) which, among other things, describes GUIs built for the [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

Although some of the schemes mentioned are fairly simple, declaratively-defined GUIs can be as complex as anything defined in code, they're just easier and terser: they say "what" you want to happen and leave it to the underlying framework to handle the "how".

Comment: It is a good answer, to point that all the examples belong to domain-specific languages. Though, I was asking for specific free-as-in-freedom examples.

Comment: The point about “declaratively-defined GUIs can be as complex as anything defined in code, they're jsut easier and terser” is very true in my opinion.

Comment: Would this mean that Shoes has got the better architecture among the rest?

Comment: @Ninad I don't know about "better" - shoes (which may be better viewed in its [green shoes](https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes) incarnation which is supported and in continuing development) can be tricky to coax into more complex, form-like structures. But that's probably true for most "simple" frameworks. I think it's just a matter of finding what works best for the individual.

Answer (score 6):

[TCL/TK](http://www.tcl.tk/) is a script language used for building GUI interactively. It is available on various platforms including Unix, Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: I know about Tk. It is terse indeed. But one thing that makes me avoid it is that Tk applications still look as “ugly” on my Linux box, as they did few years ago. I'm not talking about a different widget set, but about the fonts. Tought, probably, it is not a problem of Tk itself, but of my distro…

Comment: Tile native themes make Tcl/Tk look pretty again. There are even themes to make it look like Gtk or Qt  http://wiki.tcl.tk/11075

Comment: I think this answer deserves a higher vote, but I cannot upvote it anymore...

Comment: The issue with fonts has been addressed in the latest versions of Tk which now support anti-aliased fonts. Personally I'm more concerned about functionality and productivity in a UI toolkit rather than with pretty fonts, and in that regard Tk has almost no peer.

Answer (score 3):

Pyjamas - http://pyjs.org - it's a desktop widget set, disguised as an AJAX-based web 2.0 widget set.  it's so very much NOT like a web widget set that i actually ported it *to* the desktop - http://pyjd.org  - using webkit (the same engine in adobe AIR, google chrome, safari etc.)

this is "hello world":

```
from pyjamas.ui.RootPanel import RootPanel
from pyjamas.ui.Button import Button
from pyjamas import Window

def greet(fred):
    Window.alert("Hello, AJAX!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = Button("Click me", greet)
    RootPanel().add(b)
```

that immediately answers the first four out of five requirements.  requirement 5 is fulfilled by this:

```
from pyjamas.ui.RootPanel import RootPanel
from pyjamas.ui.HorizontalPanel import HorizontalPanel
from pyjamas.ui.HTML import HTML

p = HorizontalPanel()
p.add(HTML("<b>Hello</b>"))
p.add(HTML("World"))
RootPanel().add(p)
```

it couldn't get any simpler.

Comment: This is very interesting. I have to give a look to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[XUL](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xul/) (it's pretty easy to use, and powerful -- much of Firefox is implemented using XUL for GUI structure, + javascript for logic handling)

The [XUL tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL_Tutorial) has some good examples. Here's one for [tabboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Tabboxes). The one at the bottom of the page has switchable tabs, buttons, edit boxes, and group boxes, and it's fairly simple (no Javascript/CSS/XBL/key bindings/etc). They then add [progressively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/More_Menu_Features) [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Popup_Menus) [stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Trees) later which is a lot of functionality for the length of the file that specifies it. (at least until you start adding javascript to handle the logic in question) If I had to do something like this in Win32 it would be a real pain.

Comment: I didn't see any easy-to-use examles of XUL use outside of Mozilla. Browsing through its Tutorial gives an impression that it is too XMLish and too verbose to be used for quick and simple GUI development. I would appreciate if you can prove the opposite.

Comment: I guess I don't have much to compare it to, other than the various win32 tools I've used, and MATLAB's GUI; from that viewpoint I've found XUL very easy. Probably your best bet is to look at one of the Firefox extensions that uses it. (lemme find one...)

Comment: i mean there's this example... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-xul1/

Comment: Your examples with tabboxes and FF extensions are convincing. I'll consider it.

Comment: I've also  found a tutorial about building stand along apps with XULRunner: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention XULRunner. :) I guess that's kind of important. I've never tried it, I've always used Firefox to run my XUL  (with the disadvantage that if your program crashes it takes down the browser :/  )

Answer (score 2):

[wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/) is a wrapper of the wxWidgets library for Lua.  It uses a Connect method to attach gui widget events to functions (functions are first class like in JS).

Answer (score 2):

[GTK-server](http://www.gtk-server.org) is extremely simple to use and can be used from more than 30 languages, including Bash and Visual Basic.

Comment: Interesting project! I never thought about accessing a real API via unixy interfaces -- my experience in commandline-driven GUIs was basically limited to kdialog. I wonder if this can be generalized to work with any API.

Comment: It is certainly very interesting. It seems to be nice for scripting-controlled GUI, but it does not look “terse”. Thank you!

Comment: How can it be much more terse than this: http://www.gtk-server.org/demo-stdin.py.txt  ?

And just to clarify, gtk-server works on Windows too, which opens up for things like running the GUI on Windows, but logic on Linux, but I digress...

Comment: You may as well say GTK.  Unless I'm misunderstanding something, it's just dynamically processed C code from strings. It appears to be more complicated than the equivalent C code; which isn't what I'd call an ideal GUI framework.

Answer (score 2):

[SDL/Swing](http://www.ikayzo.org/confluence/display/SSW/Home) is extremely terse, readable, unobtrusive (283k lib with no dependencies) and easy to use. Example:

```
menus {
    "File" {
        "Open" do="open" // calls "open()" in the controller
        "---"
        "Exit" do="exit"
    }
}
```

Its open source but enjoys commercial support from Ikayzo.com. Ports for .NET and iOS are underway.

Answer (score 1):

I juat came across [SDL/Swing](http://ikayzo.org/confluence/display/SSW/Home;jsessionid=673750C9685362ACA8E5EFA8015650C3) today.

Comment: Looks like an interesting domain-specific language. Just a note for who doesn't follow links: SDL is not for Simple Directmedia Layer here.

Answer (score -2):

You should have a look at XAML if you're on the .NET platform

Comment: It is not free (open source). And even though there is a XAML compiler for Mono (http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/Xaml_compiler_for_mono), I am not sure if it is 100% compatible, or will remain such.