# Free Alternative to VB6 (easy gui building and programming)

Tags: vb6, rad

I wonder if anyone knows any free alternative to VB6.

I need (or want), some easy gui building and ability to program.

I have no problem with learning any program language, I just want the gui building to be as easy as possible.

Thnx in advance

Sorry, I wasn't really clear before, I was trying to stay way from Microsoft... open source would be great, but freeware is also OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Very simple, terse and easy GUI programming “frameworks”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470468/very-simple-terse-and-easy-gui-programming-frameworks)

Comment: What do you mean by free? do you mean the tools, ui designers? in that case, microsoft has free versions of most of their development tools, in express editions. Visual Studio Express, SQL Server Express, etc... And they don`t charge you for the program language itself.

Comment: @CharlesB The question you have selected as a possible duplicate is for *declarative* and *open source* frameworks. I.e. not a duplicate.

Comment: Related questions (not exact duplicates) [basic compilers for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152/basic-programming) and [open source GUI framework for windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919029/best-language-tool-to-develop-gui-on-windows) and [lightweight GUI framework on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272764/what-is-the-quickest-path-to-writing-a-lightweight-gui-program-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

Why not try anything different? Do you know Delphi? Nice, clean and easy with a lot of adapters an wrappers. The free version is Lazarus.

http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/

Comment: **Platforms**: `Windows`, `Linux`, `MacOS`, `Android`, `Ios`.  **Visual Designer**: `YES`. [SCREENSHOTS](https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Screenshots). **LICENSE**:`Open Source LGPL`

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Basic Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-basic-express) or [C# Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express) perhaps?

Comment: +1 for staying with what the question asker asked about...awkward phrasing: means I'm glad you stuck w/ MSoft, since he already understands a bit of it w/ VB6 experience.

Comment: If we want's to stick with Microsoft stuff that would be good. Although, the express versions have some limitations. It depend on what he's aiming to do.

Answer (score 1):

A newer option we have is [B4J](http://www.b4x.com/b4j.html), which is not open source but it is free.

The programming language is somewhere between VB and VB.Net, perhaps closest to the abandoned Jabaco language.  It targets Java and JavaFX so the resulting programs are cross-platform, but the development tools require Windows today.